# EPPlus exception on loading uploaded file in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, epplus

Here's my code. Its purpose is to count the number of lines where the first column has text in it.

```
ExcelWorksheet sheet = null;
using (ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(new MemoryStream(_fileBytes)))
{
  sheet = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
}

int rows = sheet.Dimension.End.Row;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
{
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheet.Cells[i, 1].Text))
    ++count;
}
```

When I just run the code outside the debugger, I get an exception at the `sheet.Cells[i, 1].Text` call:

```
Package object was closed and disposed, so cannot carry out operations 
on this object or any stream opened on a part of this package.
```

When I step through it with the debugger, I get the same exception... UNLESS I have this in my Watch window: `sheet.Cells[1, 1].Text`. If I run the debugger over the code (ie. press F5), from before the `sheet` object is initialized, I get the exception. If I *step through* the code with that snipped in my Watch window, NO EXCEPTION. The code works flawlessly. The Watch window correctly shows the contents of the first cell. What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the exception because you are trying to access the worksheet of the `ExcelPackage` outside of the `using` statement (disposes the package).

```
using (ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(new MemoryStream(_fileBytes)))
{
    sheet = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
    int rows = sheet.Dimension.End.Row;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= rows; ++i)
    {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sheet.Cells[i, 1].Text))
      ++count;
    }
}
```

By the way, you can shorten the code with Linq:

```
using (ExcelPackage pkg = new ExcelPackage(new MemoryStream(_fileBytes)))
{
    var sheet = pkg.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    int count = sheet.Cells[1, 1, sheet.Dimension.End.Row, 1]
        .Count(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text));
}
```

Comment: (a) duh. *facepalm* the using statement is there for a reason. (b) oh yeah hey linq that thing i use for everything else i brainfarted on here. nice.